# SQLAlchemy many to many relationship not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hey guys Im trying to set up 2 models with a many to many relationship, basically the 1st model is a "trainer" model and the 2nd model is a "matches" model and the match model will have 2 trainers in the model who will have to battle each other, and then the trainers model will have a list of different matches they need to complete. I have set up the 2 models and a association model and i keep getting this error il show below.

association model.

'''

```
association_table = db.Table('association', Base.metadata,
    db.Column('trainers_id', db.ForeignKey('trainers.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('matches_id', db.ForeignKey('matches.id'), primary_key=True))
```

'''

Trainer model

'''

```
class Trainer(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "trainers"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True )
    trainername = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    matches=relationship('Match', secondary= association_table, 
        back_populates='trainers')
```

'''

matches model

'''

```
class Match(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "matches"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    trainers= relationship("Trainer",secondary= 
        association_table, back_populates="matches")
```

'''

and i keep getting this error

'''

sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'association.matches_id' could not find table 'matches' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

'''

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using vanilla SQLAlchemy ORM. [This code](https://pastebin.com/BjYVgYWG) works fine for me.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).